# Extra List array in Spring Boot JSON Response Output

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Json response structure return from service is not as expected. Not sure where is the extra List object come from. Sorry for my bad english

Actual Result :

```
{"List": [{
            "customerNumber": "111",
            "amount": 75675
        },
        {
            "customerNumber": "222",
            "amount": 30150
        },
        {
            "customerNumber": "333",
            "amount": 120100
        },
        {
            "customerNumber": "444",
            "amount": 50000
        }]}
```

Expected Result:

```
[{"customerNumber": "111",
           "amount": 75675},
        {"customerNumber": "222",
            "amount": 30150},
        {"customerNumber": "333",
            "amount": 120100},
        { "customerNumber": "444",
            "amount": 50000}]
```

Controller and Service use to retrieve result from database and return as json in response

```
 @PostMapping(path = "/customer-list")
public List<CustomerListingBean> getCustomerListing(@RequestBody CustomerListingBean pl) {
  CustomerListingBean row = new CustomerListingBean();
    List<CustomerListingBean> custList = new ArrayList<>();
         custList = indCustomerSearchEngine.getCustomerSearchListing(pl.getCustomerNumber());
        return custList;
}
public List getCustomerSearchListing(String customerNumber) {
List newList= new ArrayList();
    List myList= customerRepository.getInquiryCustomerSearchList( customerNumber );
    for (Iterator itr = myList.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        Object[] col = (Object[]) itr.next();
        CustomerListingBean polRow = new CustomerListingBean();
        polRow.setCustomerNumber((col[0] != null) ? col[0].toString() : "");
        polRow.setAmount((col[1] != null) ? col[1].toString() : "");
        newList.add(polRow);
              return newList;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't be using raw `List`s. Take the compiler/IDE warnings to heart, and fix that. Once you've done that, your problem should be obvious and easy to fix, since you know which List will contain which type.

Comment: You seem to be missing a closing brace. Is that where your return statement is?

Comment: @tgdavies I accidentally deleted it when edit the content, in my actual code there's a closing brace.

Comment: Are you mentioning any custom JSONSerializer in the spring boot configuration file, I mean in application properties?  can you share the pom.xml configuration as well ?

Comment: @Hareesh, dont have any custom JSONSerializer, i just using spring boot version 2.7.5

Comment: okay, if you share the pom.xml configuration, it will help. Because 'List', does not get added by any JSON converter, either you might be having custom response handler or json serializer that you have in the pom.xml can cause this.

Comment: Finally figure out the root cause of this, it was due to spring.jackson.serialization.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE=true in my application.properties

Comment: @Newbee: welcome and congratulations for finding the cause. Please make an answer and accept it. It will help others.